# How do I get the arc of the circumference in the exercise?

Tags: geometry

I have this exercise:
[image]

So my development was:

Draw a line $OB$, that measures $r$ = radius.

The line $OD$ also measures $r$

If the arc $BC = 100$, so the arc $BW = 80$

Then, the triangle $ODB$ is isosceles of $BD$ base and sides of $r$

Since, the arc $BW = 80$ and $\angle{BDW}$ is the center angle, so $\angle{BDO = 80}$, besides the triangle $ODB$ is isosceles, then $\angle{OBD} = 80$, so the center angle $\angle{DOB} = 20$, therefore the arc $BD = 20$.

In a picture:

[image]

But according to the guide the result must be $40$, ¿What is wrong with my development?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your argument. It is probably just an error or misprint in the guide.

Comment: By the way, WBD= 80 is not correct.

Comment: @Seyed, was $\angle{OBD}$, edited.

Comment: That is a very badly drawn picture. It looks like the center of arc BD is W, not O.

Comment: Yes it looks, but i need know why my answer is wrong